# launch application at boot in root environment, then monitor and if closes or crashes relaunch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bash, python

I have a question regarding how i can launch an application, written in python, as soon as boot has been completed. This application needs to run with full permissions, so that passwords are not required, as there are two commands that it runs with sudo.

I also need it to relaunch the application with the same permissions if the application shutdown.

I've done similar things, but never all together. For instance, to launch at boot. I would throw a short script that calls the application I want in another directory, in the init.d directory. Then by doing "update-rc.d app defaults", it will auto launch as part of the startup scripts for Ubuntu

for relaunching a program if it crashes another simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
while True:
    print("\nStarting " + filename)
    p = Popen("python " + filename, shell=True)
    p.wait()
```

gets the job done. I can insert the application name at filename so I don't have to supply it as part of the arguments when I call it.

my main issue is the application I'm running needs to run in root environment, autolaunch at boot, and relaunch if its shutdown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sounds like you want [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: wasn't upstart replaced with systemd?

Comment: Either way, preferable to rolling your own custom script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after getting a suggestion from Glenn Jackman, I started to spend some more time looking at upstart/systemd. I ended up looking at systemd and figuring out a number of aspects of what I was looking for.

one of the concerns was that up until now I needed to run the software in a root environment, as some of the vendor software I was using required it. It appears that when you set up a service with systemd, everything is run with root privileges. So that took care of one of my issues.

As far as launching at boot up and managing any shutdowns of the software, it was handled with a very simple unit file, located at /lib/systemd/system/app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=this does something
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
exec executes my app
Restart
RestartSec

[Install]
wantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next I enabled the new service through the use of systemctl

```
sudo systemctl enable app.service
sudo systemctl daemon.reload
sudo systemctl start app.service
```

this enabled the launch at bootup, and tested it out right now.

Again thanks to Glenn for pointing me in the right direction.